# Where can I find open source Medical Image Datasets for capillary Segmentation?

Tags: data-request, medical

Where can I find open source medical datasets for Nail fold capillaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open-Access Medical Imaging repositories are available all over the internet. A list of Medical Imaging *datasets* is provided by [Giorgos Sfikas](https://github.com/sfikas) on his [`medical-imaging-datasets`](https://github.com/sfikas/medical-imaging-datasets) repository. Here, you will find several "search-engines" for medical data. Nevertheless, it could be interesting to follow both [Stephen R. Aylward's](http://www.aylward.org/notes/open-access-medical-image-repositories) list of repositories and the [SICAS Medical Image Repository](https://www.smir.ch/). I hope that helps too.